# Jenkins Jacoco Plugin not linking Groovy source files

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jacoco

Is there a way to configure the Jenkins Jacoco Plugin to link Groovy source files to the coverage report? The coverage statistics are calculated correctly, however, in a mixed Java/Groovy Project, only the Java files are linked. The configuration looks as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to the latest release (3.0.3) I was able to fix that issue. However you still need to manually tell the plugin to check for `*.groovy` source files, e.g.:

```
jacoco classPattern: 'build/classes',
       execPattern: 'build/jacoco/test.exec',
       sourceInclusionPattern: '**/*.groovy', // new option required to tell the plugin to search for *.groovy source files
       sourcePattern: 'src,test'
```

Answer (score 2):

Based upon [this bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43310), it looks like the 2.2+ releases have changed how source code is linked in the report such that it only works for *.java files. One possible work-around is to downgrade the JaCoCo plugin to 2.1.0. This is what we did and it works; although I am not sure what features and bug fixes we give up in 2.2+ so it might not be worth it in your situation.

It looks like there is [a Pull Request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/pull/85) that needs to be reviewed and merged so that it can be released in an upcoming version.